# page event 'page:beforein' can't be fire on framework7 2.x version

Tags: html-framework-7

I upgrade framework7 version from 1.6 to 2.3. 
I found page event"pageBeforeInit" can't normaly work. So I check laster document. and change page event to "page:beforein". code as below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeuNH.png)

Comment: paste your code instead of attaching image of it.

Comment: try 'pageBeforeIn' instead of 'page:beforein' and check